# Content-Language metadata field in GCS object not allowing ISO-639-2 from API

Tags: google-cloud-storage

While trying to update the [Content-Language metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#content-language) field of an object to ISO-639-2 field from the UI works fine, when trying to do the same from http API, it fails with an invalid argument error. The official documentation page states that ISO-639-1 codes are supported (although the link goes to 639-2).

Any ideas on how to update the Content-Language via http/json for objects in ISO-639-2 ? Or it's possible the UI treats it differently?

Response from GetObject for an object with ISO-639-2 updated via ui

```
{
  "kind": "storage#object",
  "id": "XXXXXXXXX/textfile.txt/XXXXXXX",
  "selfLink": ...,
  "mediaLink": ...,
  "name": "textfile.txt",
  "bucket": "XXXXXX",
  "generation": "XXXXXX",
  "metageneration": "2",
  "contentType": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
  "storageClass": "STANDARD",
  "size": "29",
  "md5Hash": "f510qpm7Jh30uKbBcN4e0A==",
  **"contentLanguage": "ach",**
  "crc32c": "4fnpOw==",
  "etag": "COet043XpPcCEAI=",
  "temporaryHold": false,
  "eventBasedHold": false,
  "timeCreated": "2022-04-21T07:56:14.769Z",
  "updated": "2022-04-21T07:57:14.321Z",
  "timeStorageClassUpdated": "2022-04-21T07:56:14.769Z",
  "metadata": {
    "gcsfuse_mtime": "2022-04-21T07:56:13.375009661Z"
  }
}
```

Error when trying to set the same value as received in the above call via json

```
    {
    "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid argument.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid argument.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you check setting "ContentLanguage": "en" or maybe "ContentLanguage": "de" in your API. I think the logic which works here, checks for ISO 639-1 format. ( which can I see in the [document](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) does not support "ach" as of now. If "en" or "de" works in the API, we would know you can only use ISO 639-1 formats. Another pointer to check, if your ContentLanguage is anyhow set to empty string. Content-Language:"" (invalid) v.s. Content-Language:NULL (valid).

Comment: Setting to "en", "de" work fine because they are ISO-639-1 but as you see "ach" is ISO-639-2 and was able to set the same from UI

Comment: Can you share the JSON API call which you are making to set 'ach' as Content Language for Cloud Storage object? I would like to test it. Then we can proceed further.

Comment: Sample request:    POST http://storage.googleapis.com:443/upload/storage/v1/b/xx/o?ifGenerationMatch=1650528251786941&ifMetagenerationMatch=2&projection=full&uploadType=resumable HTTP/1.1
Host: storage.googleapis.com:443
User-Agent: gcsfuse/unknown (Go version go1.18-pre13 cl/434556159 +428533fab4) 
Content-Length: 203
Authorization: **
Content-Type: application/json
X-Upload-Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip
 
{"bucket":"test_directory","contentLanguage":"ach","contentType":"text/plain; charset=utf-8","name":"textfile.txt","storageClass":"STANDARD"}

Comment: @Swetha Please have a look at the answer below.

Comment: @AviD Please have a look at the answer below and see if that's what you were talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your case, and it seems like you are right. Content-Language only allows [ISO 639-1](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) language codes for the supported values of this metadata.

When Content-Language was set to “ach” in JSON POST API call it gave me errors “curl: (3) Failed to convert ach” to ACE; string contains a disallowed character” but when set to “en”/ “de”/ “aa” it works fine and gives a HTTP 200 response.  I think the logic which works here, checks for ISO 639-1 format.

I have gone through the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#content-language), and it  says clearly “Refer to [ISO 639-1](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) language codes for the supported values of this metadata.”  Maybe it routes to ISO 639-2 page, because it contains both ISO 639-1 and ISO 639-2 codes, out of which it mentions it only supports ISO 639-1 language codes. You can check out this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object-resumable#request_headers) as well.

Raise a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187243&template=0) here so that the Content-Language supports ISO 639-2 language code in API calls.

Comment: Agreed that it supports only ISO 639-1 codes. But ISO 639-1 codes are not available for all languages. for eg, if we take Acoli language, we are able to set the language to Acoli from the UI and in the GET call,  we are receiving the language as "ach". But when we try to update the object and set the language as "ach", it is not working. If ISO 639-2 codes are not supported, why are we getting it in respose of GET call.

Comment: I understand your question and concern. It would be better if you can open a [Google Support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases) for the same or maybe create a [public issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187243&template=0) for Google Cloud Storage explaining the details and problems you are facing. It would be taken care of with priority.